# Postgres - Column out of range in PreparedStatement - java

Tags: java, postgresql

got a problem with a preparedstatement using Java 1.7.0.67 on Windows 8.1...

Basically I get an error as follows (from  the test):

```
2014-08-17 16:56:37 org.help
SEVERE: Strt Testing
2014-08-17 16:56:37 org.help
SEVERE: Before pstText: SELECT "lineText" FROM "public"."dbText_?" WHERE "Textid" = '?'
2014-08-17 16:56:37 org.help
SEVERE: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
```

I can see it's telling me I have no ? but they are there for all to see in the **before** setString message.

Can anyone see what is wrong with what I'm doing - I'm new to PreparedStatements and I think it's right...

thanks and regards
Seán

```
        String zLocale = "en_EN";
        PreparedStatement pst1 = null;

        logger.severe("Strt Testing");

        String sql1;
        sql1= "SELECT \"lineText\" FROM \"public\".\"dbText_?\" WHERE \"Textid\" = \'?\';";
        pst1 = con.prepareStatement(sql1);

        logger.severe("Before pstText: "+ pst1.toString());
        pst1.setString(1, "ABCDEF-001");
        pst1.setString(2, zLocale);
        logger.severe("After pstText: "+ pst1.toString());

        logger.severe("Done Testing");
```

Comment: Parameters are not string replacements. A prepared statement is a statement that the database will prepare. The database must be able to compute the execution plan for the query. Without even knowing which table the query uses, it's impossible for the database to prepare the execution plan. Also, the whole point of prepared statements is to avoid having to quote values, and format dates in a given format. So placeholder must not be inside quotes.

Comment: Got it - my reference material for PreparedStatement did not make that clear...as I said - I'm new to them and I was looking at string replacement as opposed to values...Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be like

```
String sql = "SELECT lineText FROM public.dbText_ABCDEF-001 WHERE Textid = ?";
```

Also you cannot have prepared statement for table names as it is only for column values